# How to reformat Datetime when retrieving it from database using linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime

I insert `Datetime` value into a SQL Server database with the following format: `dd-MM-yy HH:mm`. If I insert `01-01-18 15:30` into database and execute command

```
select datetimeColumn from mytable
```

I get back `2018-01-01 15:30:00.000`. But if I retrieve all records of the table which contains the column with datetime type like

```
meetings = meetings.Where(m => m.meeting_name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()));
```

`datetime` values become like `01-Jan-18 3:30:00 PM`.

How can I keep datetime format the same as the format that I've inserted?

Comment: DateTime doesn't have a format. You have to format it the way you want when you display it.

Comment: @ Gert Arnold : how can I do that with linq?

Comment: @user2905416 this is nothing to do with LINQ; this is to do with your UI code. So: where are you *displaying* it? **That** is the code you need to change. Again: a datetime *does not have a format* - either in C# or in the database; it is a pure number. It only has a format when we start talking about displaying it in a UI

Comment: @ Gert Arnold, Marc Gravell: Got it, Thanks you guys...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server stores data as two `intergers`, the first one reserved for the date and the 2nd one for the time.

```
meetings = meetings.Where(m => m.meeting_name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()));
```

So by querying you just read `date-time` as is! All you need to do is to format datetime in your desired string format, for example:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var dateTimeFormmated = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffff");
// 2018-01-26 05:52:54.3250
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server stores the data as one or more integers, depending on the data type. Numbers are what being stored, not formatted strings. The same applies to other database providers for datetime/timestamp database types.

For instance DATETIME data type. According to SQL Server documentation, the database engine stores a DATETIME value as two integers. The first integer represents the day and the second integer represents the time. The days can range from January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999, and the times can range from 00:00:00.000 through 23:59:59.997, with the default value being 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000.

The formatted string representation you see in say sql management studio or in any application, is done by the application showing the sql query result for you. This means that the burden of supporting different date/time formats lies with the application doing sql commands.